# How to get list of users in parse using Android App

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

We are developing push notification using android, and we are done with sending push notification mobile to mobile with three mobiles. Now we need to get list of users from parse. Actually we are tried with that but we are getting the current user only.

`String i=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("user")`;

The above line retrieves only the current user but we need list of all the users in the Parse installation.

[image]

We need list of names like `sam`, `sony`, `tab` as per screenshot.

Comment: It seems like a fine question, but it has a weirdly high up-vote count with only 31 views.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of query cannot be performed from the client without leaving private keys within the app, which you don't want to do.

I addressed this by having an intermediate server that the Android app queries, then the intermediate server uses the [Parse Rest API for queries](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries) to get the required information, without leaking your keys to the outside world, and returns it to the client.

You can also use [Cloud Modules](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide) to write your own JavaScript that performs the queries on Parse's own servers.